# Deleted Messages conversations inconsistent between devices

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, icloud, messages, data-synchronization

OSX native messaging app is set to Sync via iCloud account. Messages sent on either device (iPhone/Macbook) DO sync without issue.

Deleting a conversation via Macbook will present the following message:

[image: Deleting a conversation via Macbook will present the following message:]

This insinuates that the deleted conversation will be removed from my iPhone, however, this is not the case! *(The same is true when deleting from iPhone)*

Comparing meessages on iPhone and Macbook, you can see many inconsistencies:

[image: Device comparision]

My desired outcome is to have conversations within Messages mirror on all devices.

If I delete a convo on iPhone I expect it to be deleted on Macbook.

If I delete a convo on Macbook I expect it to be deleted on iPhone.

I have tried logging in/out of my iCloud account on both devices to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

iPhone > Settings > Name > iCloud > Messages was not set to sync.

Setting it to Sync has resolved the issue.